# How to tell which Facebook Page my Page Tab App is installed on

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out what Page has installed my Facebook Canvas App?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5587784/how-can-i-find-out-what-page-has-installed-my-facebook-canvas-app)

I have a facebook app and I have installed this app to a page tab through the graph api. It worked fine so far.

Once this app may be installed to a lot of pages, what do I need is, within my app, to be able to get the ID of the page whom is holding the app.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just like in forums, try to search before asking. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is passed as a part of a signed_request to your app, it is called "page":

> A JSON object containing the page id string, the liked boolean if the
>   user has liked the page, the admin boolean if the user is an admin.
>   Only available if your app is an iframe loaded in a Page tab.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/